# Is there an equivalent of "new" that would allow me to make an object mapped onto shared memory?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management

I'm currently trying to make two processes work together in win32. Is there some sort of "new" function that can be used like:

```
baseAddress = memoryMappedFile->FirstFreePosition();
SharedObject* sharedObject = new(baseAddress) SharedObject()
```

- I know the above looks a little funky but is there something like
  that?
- If there's nothing like the above does that mean I have to do malloc and free stuff with all the primitive datatypes that needs to be passed over from process to process?

Comment: `SharedObject* sharedObject = new(baseAddress) SharedObject()` Looks like you may have just invented [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new).

Comment: Thanks brother. it looks like I'll be having fun tonight.

Comment: Note that you will also have to call the destructor explicitely (i.e. `delete` will not do it for you, you need e.g. `sharedObject->~SharedObject()`). If you have C++17, there are also some useful functions in the standard library, see e.g. [uninitialized_default_construct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_default_construct) and friends.

Comment: ~SharedObject(). I'll be sure to call it. Cheers.

Comment: Although you can share *memory* between processes, you can't share *objects* between processes.